# How can I prevent Google Hangouts from opening on all workspaces?

Tags: window, workspaces

When I open Chrome or launch Google Hangouts, the hangouts window opens on all workspaces.  I always have to right-click on the title and un-check "Always on Visible Workspace"

Is there any way to keep this from being default behavior every time I launch Hangouts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In hangouts, click the "hamburger" menu (or on your name) in the top left to go to the main options.
In there (under "Hangouts App Settings") is a checkbox for "Always on Visible Workspace", uncheck it.

Comment: derp. was this always there?

Comment: I don't see this option on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Found it. Needed to install the app instead of the extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third-party tool, [devilspie2](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/) to control the behavior of application windows as they are created.  The following devilspie2 config file will keep the Hangouts window from showing up on all workspaces:

```
if (get_window_name() == "Google Hangouts") then
    unpin_window();
end
```

Save it in a file named `hangouts.lua` in the devilspie2 config directory (for Fedora 24, that's `.config/devilspie2/`.

Finally, be sure to set devilspie2 to launch when your desktop environment starts, and you should be good to go.